# What is the biggest crossover universe in TV?

Tags: crossovers

Franchise movies have crossed over for [over a hundred years](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/2188/9682), however despite the long and serialised nature of TV, they're still relatively uncommon besides spin-offs. Crossover episodes between shows indicate both shows take place in the same universe, and long running shows often have multiple over their course.

If you take all the crossover episodes of a TV show, and combine it with every crossover episodes from that show (et cetera), how many shows comprise the biggest universe? As "crossover" is quite vague on its own, I'm imposing these definitions on it:

> - The episode takes place at the location of one or both shows
> - The episode features at least one character from the second show, played by the same actor.
>
>   - Parodies of a show featuring a cameo by an original cast member **do not** count (e.g. [Saturday Night Live and Breaking Bad](http://hollywoodlife.com/2013/09/29/aaron-paul-snl-cameo-video-breaking-bad-finale/))
> - Movies don't count as episodes

For example, The CSI-Verse:

1. [CSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI:_Crime_Scene_Investigation) and [CSI: Miami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI:_Miami) in [Cross-Jurisdictions](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0534673/)
2. CSI: Miami and [CSI: NY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI:_NY) in [Manhattan Manhunt](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0534871/)
3. CSI and CSI: New York in [Hammer Down](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1522457/)
4. CSI and [Without a Trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_a_Trace) in [Who and What](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1108057/)

There are additional crossover episodes within the shows, but only unique shows count here, so this is **4**. Though soon it will be 5 as the CSI episode [Kitty](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3589954/) has been [commissioned](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/cbs-orders-csi-spinoff-series-699995) for a full series.

Comment: Do time travels count? I'm thinking of Star Trek - the different Series are connected via time travels (But maybe it is in conflict with the 'movies don't count'-rule).

Comment: @knut Yep they count

Comment: I just don't like a question that can't have a definitive answer. It seems more like a discussion if that's the case.

Comment: @knut: Does Star Trek count *because of time travels*? The different series have a lot more connections that are *not* time travels (even when discounting the very sparse character cameos), and moreover, it's not even true - TNG, DS9 and VOY all play within the course of a few decades and at least TNG + DS9 as well as DS9 + VOY are not linked pairwise by time travels at all. In the realm of fantasy/scifi, I suggest "The episode features a fictional civilization/fictional organization from the second show." as an additional definition, though the word "crossover" seems like an understatement.

Comment: @KevinHowell Why can't it have a deifnitive answer? It seems to outline the conditions for "crossover" pretty well and gives an objective criterium (most individual shows). The answer with the most shows connected this way obviously wins. Or have missed an aspect of the question?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The only aspect that you missed is the part where MrLore typed "Due to the ongoing nature of TV, no definitive answer is possible," but I agree with you I think a definitive answer is possible but if the OP states that it isn't possible it feels more like a discussion.

Comment: I didn't think it was, but I don't see anyone making a bigger chain than what Bill the Lizard mentioned

Comment: @KevinHowell Ok, I tended to ignore that last sentence, since I didn't like it so much either, probably for the same reasons you did.

Comment: @MrLore Yeah any theory that can combine 51 shows and probably counting into one universe really does set the bar high. That's why I asked in chat about this theory because it's not airtight but does cover so much ground.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Consider also that MrLore stated "feel free to post universes which are smaller but more interesting (such as containing no spin-offs), one universe per post." which sounds very much like a forum discussion and not a QA with a direct, definitive answer.  If not for that line, I'd be perfectly fine with this question.

Comment: *The episode features at least one character from the second show, played by the same actor.* I assume from this line that you're restricting the question to live-action TV but it would be good to make that clearer.

Comment: How about on the CW with the Arrowverse? Each season they have crossovers and for this season Arrow, Flash, Supergirl, Legends of Tommorrow and Batwoman.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to [The Tommy Westphall Universe Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Westphall#The_Tommy_Westphall_Universe_Hypothesis), nearly all of American television takes place in the mind of an autistic child.  The theory first appeared in 2002, when writer Dwayne McDuffie wrote [Six Degrees of St. Elsewhere](http://www.slushfactory.com/content/EpupypyZAZTDOLwdfz.php) for the Slush Factory.

> For those of you don’t know, *St. Elsewhere* was a slick, well written and acted drama series about the doctors, administrators and patients of the fictional Boston hospital, St. Eligius (nicknamed St. Elsewhere by the staff). After a long, award-winning run, in the very last moments of the show's final episode, it was revealed that all of the events of the show were merely the prolonged daydream of an autistic child. None of it "really" happened. Whether you like this final twist (for what it’s worth, I didn’t), it’s a legitimate ending to a self-contained show. But if *St. Elsewhere* played by the rules of comics, either they wouldn’t have been allowed to do it, or they would have precipitated a crisis in TV Land far bloodier than DC Comics' *Crisis On Infinite Earths*. Why? Because crossover-wise, *St. Elsewhere* is the Kevin Bacon of TV shows.
>
> Stay with me now, this is complicated but kind of fun.
>
> Characters from *St. Elsewhere* have appeared on *Homicide*, which means that show is part of the autistic child’s daydream and likewise doesn’t exist. It gets worse. The omnipresent Detective John Munch from *Homicide* has appeared on *X-Files*, *Law & Order* and *Law & Order: SVU*. *Law & Order* characters have appeared on *Law & Order: Criminal Intent*. *X-Files* characters have appeared on *The Lone Gunmen* and *Millennium*. Characters from *Chicago Hope* have appeared on *Homicide*. Characters from *Picket Fences* have appeared on *Chicago Hope*. All those shows are gone (if you count cartoons, which makes this game much too easy, the *X-Files* characters have appeared on *The Simpsons*. *The Critic* has also appeared on *The Simpsons*. Dead).
>
> Characters from *Picket Fences* have appeared on *Ally McBeal*. Ally McBeal has appeared on *The Practice*. Characters from *The Practice* have appeared on *Boston Public*. Autistic daydreams, every one.
>
> But that's not all. *St Elsewhere* characters have appeared on *Cheers*, so *Fraiser* doesn’t exist. Neither do *Wings*, *Caroline In The City* or *The Tortellis* but who cares? Well, maybe you do, because *Caroline In The City* once crossed over with *Friends*, which crossed over with *Mad About You*, which crossed over with *Seinfeld* and *The Dick Van Dyke* show. None of them happened in our new, shared continuity.
>
> *St. Elsewhere* also shared characters with *The White Shadow* and *It’s Gary Shandling’s Show*. Garry Shandling crossed over with *The Andy Griffith show* (no, really!). So *Gomer Pyle*, *Mayberry RFD*, and *Make Room for Daddy/The Danny Thomas Show* are gone. *Make Room For Daddy* takes out *I love Lucy*.
>
> And there’s more, *St. Elsewhere* also shares continuity with *M*A*S*H*, so *Aftermash* and *Trapper John MD* are out of there.
>
> Now here’s a good one, *St. Elsewhere* shared a patient with *The Bob Newhart Show*, so the *Bob Newhart Show* is part of the grand daydream. *The Bob Newhart Show* crossed over with *Murphy Brown*, which in turn links to, among many others: *Julia*, *The Nanny*, *Everybody Loves Raymond* and *I Dream of Jeannie*! Meanwhile, the series *Newhart* was revealed to be a nightmare had by Bob Newhart’s character on the *Bob Newhart Show*. *Newhart* crossed over with *Coach*, which connects it to *Grace Under Fire*, *Ellen*, and *Drew Carey*. Drew Carey takes out *Home Improvement* and *NYPD Blue*.
>
> All of these shows (and many more that I left out or missed) are daydreams of *St. Elsewhere’s* autistic kid.

That's forty-seven shows, by my count, that exist in this shared universe.  You can also add *Boston Legal*, which shares many characters with *The Practice*, and both *The Single Guy* and *Hope and Gloria* for their crossovers with *Friends* to bring the count to an even fifty.  Wait, no. *Joey* makes fifty-one. (We can keep adding to the list, since many shows that came out after 2002 cross over with shows already mentioned.)

Comment: In addition to the objections listed to this hypothesis, it is also interesting to note that in some series, a cross-over is done with a show that is (either earlier or later) referenced as being fictional.  For instance, if on the show two characters talk about some detail of Joey on "Friends" the night before and then the following week they meet the actual Joey Tribbiani, which is it?  Is he real (on the show) or not?

Comment: According to [The Master List](http://thetommywestphall.wordpress.com/the-master-list/), Tommy Westphall can be linked to nearly 400 shows.

Comment: Thanks Kris!  It also occurs to me that, by the transitive property, we could instead argue that all of these shows were part of Bob Newhart's nightmare in Newhart, right?

Comment: Ok, how does ST:TNG connect to The John Larroquette Show??

Comment: @ChrisJ.Breisch Good question! I'd love to see more details on how some of those shows are linked. A lot of them are obvious (direct spin-offs), and I even remember a lot of the cross-overs mentioned, but some seem pretty strange. This might spawn a whole series of follow-up questions.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Breisch Apparently that is a shaky connection because his show references Yoyodyne. It's a fictional company that appears in many sci-fi movies and tv shows. Not a good connection really.

Comment: It's an interesting theory, and to be honest, I haven't read the whole "story", since I simply don't know at least half those shows, but one thing I'd still like to consider, which makes the whole thing far less "awesome": Let's assume I meet someone on the street and the following night I dream of that person. From the perspective described above, that person would be fictional (since they're from my dream), but at the same time the dream is based off an actual person.

Comment: I believe a lot of McDuffie's source was from Thomas Holbrook's Poobala website, which has been hosting this crossover information since long before 2002: http://poobala.com/crossoverlist.html

Comment: The Cheers crossover is invalid, as it happened on St Elsewhere. The kid watched Cheers and had the characters from Cheers appear in his fictional St. Elsewhere universe that he dreams of. Same thing with the Newhart crossover. The only crossovers that are valid are ones where characters from St. Elsewhere appear on another show. But of course that other show is an imagination of the kid with the snow globe.

Comment: 47 shows?  And now I lament my vote which changed this answer's total score from 47 to 48.  47.

Comment: The connections made in The Master List mentioned by @Plutor are not vetted. For example, the film *Executive Decision* used an airline called "Oceanic Airlines". Several television series used stock footage from it. The Master List creates crossovers with *LOST* from the use of that stock footage.

Comment: "Tim Allen reprised his role as **Home Improvement‘s** Tim “The Tool Man” Taylor during Thursday’s **Last Man Standing**." from [here}(https://tvline.com/2021/01/07/last-man-standing-home-improvement-crossover-explained-tim-allen/).

Answer (score 24):

Detective [John Munch](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0004858/), played by the same actor, Richard Belzer, has appeared in at least a single episode of the following distinct television series, though in some cases, multiple episodes:

"Law & Order: Special Victims Unit"
"30 Rock"
"The Wire"
"Arrested Development"
"Law & Order: Trial by Jury"
"The Beat"
"Law & Order"
"Homicide: Life on the Street"
"The X-Files"

Using him as the singular connection point, nine different television universes can be seen to be paired. The character John Munch also appeared on Sesame Street, however, not played by the same actor.

Comment: I don't know the *Arrested Development* episode with him (maybe from the 4th Netflix-season?), but judging from the show's nature, that might be hard on the edge of parody, but maybe that edge is hard to define anyway.

Comment: The episode is from season 3 - if you watch the clips, you find George Michael planning a birthday party for Maeby, from her address book. Seeing as she's a fake TV producer in that season, it probably has Munch as a party attendee.

Answer (score 4):

What about the Happy Days Universe?

- Happy Days
- Joanie Loves Chachi
- Laverne and Shirley
- Mork and Mindy
- Sabrina the Teenage Witch

Comment: Sabrina the Teenage Witch? How is that linked?

Comment: Sabrina actually met Potsie in an episode of Sabrina the Teenage Witch

Answer (score 4):

## If we disqualify the Tommy Westphall Universe…

An issue with the Tommy Westphall universe is that many shows are only linked by Easter eggs (e.g. the [TARDIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS) is in the background of a single shot, things like [Morley cigarettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley_(cigarette)) or the [Yoyodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoyodyne) company exist), which isn't really in the spirit of the question.

Also, plenty of shows in that universe are not at all intended to be in continuity with each other. For instance, *CSI: Miami* as it's own show is not intended to be in continuity with either *The Adventures of Superman* or *The Addams Family*. So if we only count shows that have explicit, intentional links to all the other shows in the shared universe, the biggest is:

### The **[Super Sentai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Sentai)** franchise (41 Shows and Growing)

English speakers may be more familiar with *Power Rangers*, which takes fighting footage from this Japanese series and dubs it in English while splicing in original English footage. It began in 1975 with *[Himitsu Sentai Gorenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himitsu_Sentai_Gorenger)* and now produces a new show every year, with the 2017-2018 show being *[Uchu Sentai Kyuranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchu_Sentai_Kyuranger)*.

The 35th show (*[Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizoku_Sentai_Gokaiger)*) was an anniversary show that made it abundantly clear that it was in continuity with all the previous shows. The first episode had all the protagonists appear together (played by suit actors, which also happened in the original shows) and some of the non-suit actor original cast members reprised their roles over the course of the series.

[image: The first 34 Super Sentai]

Each subsequent show is also in continuity with the show before it, with the final shot of each show showing a [hand-off](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Hand-Off) between the Red Ranger of the current show and the Red Ranger of the next show. There is often a team-up episode between the current show and previous show as well, although nowadays, those are usually done in theatrical films. Speaking of which…

### If we count movies, then the Super Sentai, Karen Rider, and Metal Heroes shared universe (84 Shows and Growing)

You said that movies don't count for this purpose, but if it did, there is the Japan-only theatrical movie *[Kamen Rider × Super Sentai × Space Sheriff: Super Hero Taisen Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamen_Rider_%C3%97_Super_Sentai_%C3%97_Space_Sheriff:_Super_Hero_Taisen_Z)*, which is a crossover between the *Super Sentai* franchise, the *[Kamen Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamen_Rider_Series)* franchise (26 shows), and the *[Metal Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Hero_Series)* franchise (17 shows). Note that *Super Sentai* is represented by *Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger*, the anniversary show listed above. So if movies were allowed, this would be a crossover universe with **84 shows** at the time of this writing.

Comment: This continuity is bigger. The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles from *Ninja Turtles: The Next Mutation* appeared in *Power Rangers in Space* "Shell Shocked".

Answer (score 2):

There were the Beverly Hillbillies/Green Acres/Petticoat Junction crossovers in the 1960s.

Answer (score 2):

[Buffy and Angel](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Buffy_The_Vampire_Slayer_and_Angel_crossover_episodes)? Quite a few episodes there.

Comment: The problem is, though, that the question seems to be more after how many *shows* and not *episodes*, which in your case would only be 2 and thus lower than any of the already existing answers.

Comment: If we're counting *episodes*, then Doctor Who/Doctor Who Original Series/Torchwood/Adventures of K9/Sarah Jane Chronicles beats Buffyverse flat.

Comment: It seems I misread the question, my apologies.

Answer (score -1):

If you’re looking for a television crossover universe with the greatest number of episodes, you should probably be looking at daytime television soap operates which have been on the air for decades and have aired thousands of episodes.  For example As the World Turns (13,858 episodes) spun off Somerset (1710 episodes) and Our Private World (38 episodes).  It has crossovers with characters from Another World (8891 episodes) and The Young and the Restless (10,692 episodes and counting) which has in turn crossovered with The Bold and the Beautiful (7103 episodes and counting).  By my count that’s well over 33,000 episodes among these series – well more than all of the Star Trek series, Doctor Who and related spinoffs or the Tommy Westphal-connected series.

Comment: As repeatedly explained, he does *not* look for the most episodes.

Answer (score -2):

Chicago Fire and Chicago PD Crossover and Law & Order
Arrow and The Flash
The Vampire Dairies and The Originals