# Biggest single episode TV crossover

Tags: crossovers

After watching episodes of TV where characters from Chicago Fire, Chicago PD and Law & Order: SVU all interact with each other in a single episode I was curious if there had ever been a bigger crossover.

After scanning Wikipedia's [list of fictional crossovers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_crossovers), I found a reference to the episode of Becker "[Drive, They Said](http://www.tv.com/shows/becker/drive-they-said-1662/)" which stars characters from three other shows *(Cosby, King of Queens, Everyone Loves Raymond)* on a fourth show *(Becker)*.

My question to you, wise oracles of StackExchange, has there been single episode crossover bigger?

Stipulations:

- All characters have to appear in the same single episode *(see example above)*
- I'm looking for characters *(example John Stamos playing Uncle Jesse from "Full House")* and not the actor playing themselves *(example John Stamos playing John Stamos the actor)*
- Live-action TV shows only please

**Edits**
Based on the comments I'm adding my stipulations:

- Fictional TV shows only
- Biggest in this instance means the largest numbers of characters from different shows on one show
- An appearance in this instance would constitute at least one line of spoken dialogue from the character to count (i.e. no pictures, but I guess a telephone call between two characters would count. If that's not getting too nitty gritty.)

**Edit**

I'm going to give this one to @cde . One of my co-workers was worried about characters who started out as a regular on one show (say *The Flash* or *Arrow*) and then became a regular on another show (say *Legends of Tomorrow*) then guest star back on their original show counting...but I see some characters from the referenced Flash episode as a regular on *Legends* then guest on *Flash* later.

In closing, even discounting the late great Dwayne McDuffie's [Tommy Westphall Universe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7igi4cbvzavahy/Crossovers_2015.jpg?dl=0) and the alive and great character [John Munch](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/JustForFun/JohnMunch) this was more complicated than I thought it would be. Thanks to everyone that commented.

Comment: I'm borderline on voting to close, simply because this is strictly a trivia question.  Can anyone change my mind on that?

Comment: Can you define biggest? Is it the most people, the most series, the most watched?

Comment: BTW, technically, any episode with [John Munch](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/JustForFun/JohnMunch) in it has a character from 10 different shows ;)

Comment: @Walt ;) I appreciate the cheeky comment but I think for the purposes of my question I would only count him as a character from one show (Homicide or SVU). It's good to poke at the boundaries of this question to figure how big the TV universe really is.

Comment: Related: [What is the biggest crossover universe in TV?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19892/49)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### "Forever Red" from *Power Rangers: Wild Force* includes characters from 9 shows with speaking roles

To commemorate the 10th anniversary of the *Power Rangers* franchise, the episode "[Forever Red](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Forever_Red)" of *[Power Rangers: Wild Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Rangers:_Wild_Force)* featured Red Rangers from every *Power Rangers* TV show to date teaming up to fight an enemy. Every one of them has speaking roles.

[image: The first 10 Red Power Rangers]

- Jason Lee Scott of *Mighty Morphin Power Rangers*
- Aurico of *Mighty Morphin Alien Rangers**
- Tommy Oliver of *Power Rangers: Zeo*
- T.J. Johnson of *Power Rangers: Turbo*
- Andros of *Power Rangers: In Space*
- Leo Corbett of *Power Rangers: Lost Galaxy*
- Carter Grayson of *Power Rangers: Lightspeed Rescue*
- Wesley Collins and Eric Myers of *Power Rangers: Time Force*
- Cole Evans of *Power Rangers: Wild Force*

<sub>* Although some debate whether *Mighty Morphin Alien Rangers* counts as a show because it technically took place at the end of *Mighty Morphin Power Rangers* Season 3, it had a different opening theme and Wikipedia classifies it as its own series.</sub>

### "The Space Pirates Appear" from *Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger* includes characters from 35 shows (without speaking roles)

Most of the characters just give a unified "hijah!" during an amazing fight scene in which nearly 200 *Super Sentai* Rangers fight an overwhelming army. Teams from all previous 34 series were present in this battle, with the titular *[Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizoku_Sentai_Gokaiger)* appearing later in the episode.

[image: The first 34 Super Sentai]

The American version of this battle was shown in the **Power Rangers: Super Megaforce** final episode, "[Legendary Battle](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Battle)", but since *Power Rangers* has had fewer seasons, only characters from 16 shows appeared, again with most only speaking by giving a unified battle cry.

[image: Power Rangers Super Megaforce Legendary Battle]

<sub>In case you didn't know, *Power Rangers* gets its fight scene footage from *Super Sentai* and films new footage in between of English-speaking actors.</sub>

## Theatrical movies with TV show characters

The question only asked for TV show episodes that had characters from different shows, but there were a few theatrical movies in the *Super Sentai* franchise that with many actors from different shows.

### *[Gokaiger Goseiger Super Sentai 199 Hero Great Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gokaiger_Goseiger_Super_Sentai_199_Hero_Great_Battle)* includes characters from all 35 Super Sentai shows, with characters from 18 of them having speaking roles

The battle in "The Space Pirates Appear" from *Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger* is revisited in this movie, with the first 34 Super Sentai teams at that point making an appearance, and the rest of the film focuses on the Gokaigers. The following characters from different shows have speaking roles:

- Tsuyoshi Kaijo of *Himitsu Sentai Gorenger*
- Sokichi Banba of *J.A.K.Q. Dengekitai*
- Daigoro Oume of *Denshi Sentai Denziman*
- Kanpei Kuroda of *Dai Sentai Goggle V*
- Rei Tachibana of *Kagaku Sentai Dynaman*
- Shirou Gou of *Choudenshi Bioman*
- Riki Honoo of *Kousoku Sentai Turboranger*
- Ryo of the Heavenly Fire Star of *Gosei Sentai Dairanger*
- Signalman of *Gekisou Sentai Carranger*
- Hyuuga of *Seijuu Sentai Gingaman*
- Umeko Kodou, Doggie Kruger, and Swan Shiratori of *Tokusou Sentai Dekaranger*
- Miyuki Ozu and Heavenly Saint Blagel of *Mahou Sentai Magiranger*
- Mele and Rio of *Juken Sentai Gekiranger*
- Satoru Akashi and Great Sword Man Zubaan of *GoGo Sentai Boukenger*
- Saki Rouyama of *Engine Sentai Go-Onger*
- Chiaki Tani, Genta Umemori, and Kaoru Shiba of *Samurai Sentai Shinkenger*
- All main characters of *Tensou Sentai Goseiger*
- All main characters of *Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger*

### Honorable Mention: *[Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger vs. Space Sheriff Gavan: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizoku_Sentai_Gokaiger_vs._Space_Sheriff_Gavan:_The_Movie)* includes a single actor playing characters from three different shows

Along with speaking roles from characters of *Kaizoku Sentai Gokaiger* and *Tokumei Sentai Go-Busters*, this crossover movie contains a single actor, Kenji Ohba, reprising his roles from three different TV shows:

[image: Kenji Ohba in his three roles, unmorphed]

[image: Kenji Ohba in his three roles, morphed]

- Shirou Akebono of *Battle Fever J*
- Retsu Ichijouji of *[Space Sheriff Gavan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Sheriff_Gavan)* (not a *Super Sentai* show)
- Daigoro Oume of *Denshi Sentai Denziman*

[image: "I've been mistaken for Space Sherrif Gavan many times too.]

Comment: My hats off to you good sir, I knew there were a whole gaggle of Power Rangers shows but I hadn't thought about crossovers.

Comment: I know that there was less face actors in the American version, but I think they had all the costume versions, even ones not aired in the US. http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/powerrangers/images/7/76/Legend_War_Original_vs_Edit.png/revision/latest?cb=20151213214434 `Some rangers who do not appear in the cliff intro appear when the Legendary Rangers are meeting with the Mega Rangers in person. Additionally, other rangers (Solaris Knight, Mercury Ranger, Rangers Gold and Silver) appeared due to Super Sentai footage.`

Comment: @cde Those Super Sentai Rangers only appear briefly through stock footage, and no story explanation is given for their presence (not to mention, they aren't present during the previous shot). So either it's a production error, or they just didn't care; take your pick.

Comment: This continuity is bigger. The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles from *Ninja Turtles: The Next Mutation* appeared in *Power Rangers in Space* "Shell Shocked".